# Is there any way to add delimiters to a string in hadoop?

Tags: string, hadoop, mapreduce, delimiter

I'm thinking to edit a each line in file and add delimiters to it in hadoop. Is it advantageous to do it in hadoop as I have very large files ?

Example:

Input file:

```
001012489MAR01856400004400
001012489FEB01856400004400
```

Output file will be

```
0010|12489|MAR|018564|0000|44|00
0010|12489|FEB|018564|0000|44|00
```

How can I achieve this? I have searched lot of blogs but didn't find a way to do it.

Comment: Question was not tagged for hive...it is tagged for mapreduce ...but accepted solution is hive!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more alternate is by using Hive ( which takes care of the programming part)

1) Create a hive **tmp**  table pointing to your HDFS raw data file location ,

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tmp (raw String) 
LOCATION '<hdfs_path>'
```

2) Create **formatted_data** table with **pipe delimeter** as seperator

```
CREATE TABLE formatted_data(
col1 string,col2 string,
col3 string,col4 string, 
col5 string,col6 string,col7 string) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';
```

3) Insert the data from **tmp** table to **formatted_data** table:

```
INSERT INTO formatted_data 
select substr(raw,0, 4),substr(raw,4, 9),substr(raw,9, 12),
substr(raw,12, 18),substr(raw,18, 22),substr(raw,22, 24),
substr(raw,24,26) from TMP ;
```

4) verify the hdfs file of '**formatted_data**' table

```
hadoop fs -cat /hive/warehouse/formatted_data/000000_0
16/08/30 10:47:31 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

 0010|012489MAR|9MAR01856400|R01856400004400|400004400|04400|400
 0010|012489FEB|9FEB01856400|B01856400004400|400004400|04400|400
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved via map-reduce or spark job. (`substring()`):

**Map-reduce (JAVA):** you only need mapper in this case. Just map your input string line with delimited string lines:

```
public class Delimeters {

    public static class DelimetersMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {

        @Override
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            //001012489FEB01856400004400
            String lineWithDelimeter = value.toString().substring(0, 4) + "|" + value.toString().substring(4, 9)
                    + "|" + value.toString().substring(9, 12) + "|" + value.toString().substring(12, 18)
                    + "|" + value.toString().substring(18, 22) + "|" + value.toString().substring(22, 24)
                    + "|" + value.toString().substring(24,26);

            System.out.println(lineWithDelimeter); //0010|12489|MAR|018564|0000|44|00

            context.write(new Text(lineWithDelimeter),new Text(""));    
        }   
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Add-Delimeters-to-flat-file");

        job.setJarByClass(Delimeters.class);
        job.setMapperClass(DelimetersMapper.class); 
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        FileSystem fs = null;
        Path dstFilePath = new Path(args[1]);
        try {
            fs = dstFilePath.getFileSystem(conf);
            if (fs.exists(dstFilePath))
                fs.delete(dstFilePath, true);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    } 

}
```

**Spark (Scala):**

```
object delimeter {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {

            val inputFile = args(0)

                val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Add-Delimeters-to-flat-file").setMaster("local")
                val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

                val txtFileLines = sc.textFile(inputFile)

                val fields = txtFileLines.map(line => line.substring(0, 4) + "|" + line.substring(4, 9)
                    + "|" + line.substring(9, 12) + "|" + line.substring(12, 18)
                    + "|" + line.substring(18, 22) + "|" + line.substring(22, 24)
                    + "|" + line.substring(24,26))

        fields.foreach(x => println(x))

            fields.saveAsTextFile(args(1))    
        }
}
```

***Update:***

1. you can use `file:///` uri to let hadoop know to look for local file system as source (same rule applies for spark):

   ```
   hadoop jar <app.jar> <package.classname> <file:///path/to/local/dir> </path/to/hdfs/>
   ```

---

Example:

```
    [cloudera@quickstart Desktop]$ hadoop jar hadoop-stack.jar so.Delimeters file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/test.txt /user/cloudera/delim
    [cloudera@quickstart Desktop]$ hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/delim/*
    0010|12489|FEB|018564|0000|44|00    
    0010|12489|MAR|018564|0000|44|00
```

2. you can have source files in `hdfs` and delete the source files in application itself after successful processing:

   ```
   int exitcode = job.waitForCompletion(true)? 0: -1;

   if (exitcode == 0){
   try {
       Path sourcePath = new Path(args[0]);
       fs = sourcePath.getFileSystem(conf);
       if (fs.exists(sourcePath))
           fs.delete(sourcePath, true);
   } catch (IOException e1) {
       e1.printStackTrace();
   }
   }
   ```
3. Create `oozie` workflow which runs application that add delimiters to target destination and shell script that deletes the source file/dir at end

Comment: i loved the spark approach ... thanks for the instant answer.. :)

Comment: As i want to save space in haoop cluster, i would like to use the files from local filesystem and add delimiters and save it to hdfs... is there any way i can do so ? because i know that mapreduce input file must be on hdfs... that's my overhead.. @BigDataLearner

Comment: yes there are many ways to do this, I have update some ideas [see answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39188147/2079249). please create new question thread if you wish to get more details on this new question...